# how to update a particular json data object which belongs to browser local-storage

Tags: javascript, json

**This is Browser localstorage Object referred as dataset**

```
let dataset = localStorage.getItem('dataset') !== null ? leech : [];
```

```
   [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "bcd"
      }
    ]
```

This is the initial data object available I want to add more field to a particular id.
This is what I want :

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "bcd",
    "status":1
  }
]
```

This my code to find the particular id

```
const user = dataset.find(user => user.id == 456);
```

Now how can I add status to user and update the user in the dataset?

Comment: If this is a specific database interface then you should probably tag it.  Like, is it for mongodb or something like that?  Or are you just talking about raw manipulation of the JavaScript objects in an array?

Comment: You already found the user so just add the property... `user.status = 1`

Comment: this is browser local storage dataset. 
I want to add a field to a particular dataset object as specified in the question.

Comment: @phil now how do I update the dataset, which will only update that particular user?

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH that should update the dataset. If you want to update the value in `localStorage`, you'll need to do so manually... `localStorage.setItem("dataset", JSON.stringify(dataset))`

Comment: @phi its done thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've already found the user by using `Array.prototype.find()` so all you need to do then is add the `status` property

```js
// const dataset = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataset"))
const dataset = [{"id":123,"name":"abc"},{"id":456,"name":"bcd"}]

const user = dataset.find(({ id }) => id === 456)
if (user) {
  user.status = 1
}

console.info(dataset)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

If you then want to store the modified data back into `localStorage`, use `localStorage.setItem()` and `JSON.stringify()`

```js
localStorage.setItem("dataset", JSON.stringify(dataset))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep `dataset` initial value, and would like to get a new array, you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "bcd"
  }
]

const output = dataset.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.id === 456) cur.status = 1;
  acc.push(cur);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

If you want to update `dataset`, you can use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "bcd"
  }
]

dataset.forEach(user => {
  if (user.id === 456) user.status = 1;
});

console.log(dataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `Array#Findindex` with callback return function. so could pass the `originaldata,searchId and update object`. In this method you could updated object easily

> **Why i suggest findIndex**
>
> Because `findindex` not running entire loop or iteration. If the match
> detect on first iteration they will break the loop and returning the
> result.For long iteration its more faster than other loop (reduce,forEach)

```js
const data = [ { "id": 123, "name": "abc" }, { "id": 456, "name": "bcd" } ]

function update(dataset,searchId,addtionObject){
  let ind = dataset.findIndex(({id}) => id == searchId);
  dataset[ind] = {...dataset[ind],...addtionObject}; //join the new and old array
  return dataset
}

console.log(update(data,456,{status:1}))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should check to make sure `ind` isn't `-1`. This also seems less clear than OP's use of `find()`

Comment: @Phil Thanks... But in my method if no index detected. Then will be the original array was returned. And also OP did't mentioning the result for invalid match of id

Comment: Even though you might not see it in the console, if the `id` is not found and `ind` is `-1`, you're still adding an array index at `-1`

Comment: @Phil you solved it. Please post it as answer. Thanks

Comment: @Phil Ya... But Array doesn't have -1 index. If i set that also invalid and not acceptable .Its  does not have any effect . And also find returning the entire object . That why i suggest findindex and also its not affect the original array (immutable)

Comment: @prasanth This is a bit complex to implement to my code but thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create new state objet, you can use immer for that.
[Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) will produce the nextState based on the mutations to the draft state.

```
import produce from "immer";

const baseState = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "abc",
  },
  {
    id: 456,
    name: "bcd",
  },
];

const nextState = produce(baseState, (draftState) => {
  draftState[1].status = 1;
});
```